# How to style MessagePrompt from Code4Fun

Tags: styles, windows-phone-7

I am using the Message Prompt from the [Code4fun toolkit for Windows Phone](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/).

I have a problem styling the component. I have tried creating a general stye for it, and also tried changing the properties before displaying the component:

```
var messagePrompt = new MessagePrompt
{
    Title = "UserControl test",
    Body = new PopupView(),
    IsAppBarVisible = true,
    IsCancelVisible = true,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(0),
    Margin = new Thickness(0),
    Padding = new Thickness(0),
    BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 82, 161)),
    Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 82, 161))
};

messagePrompt.Show();
```

The Background is set with the correct color, but the BorderThickness, the Margin and the Padding settings are ignored!

I have tried google for some stying examples, but not with any luck!

So, how can I style the MessagePrompt component from coding4fun?

Comment: Did you try to open it up in Expression Blend, make a copy of the template and style it in the xaml and call your style as a resource over to your instance instead?

Comment: I did a "Edit Template" by creating a copy and this came out empty!

Comment: I'm not directly familiar with the code4fun controls but somewhere those values are likely named in the xaml template. You should be able to find their template by either right-clicking the control on your design space and doing the "Edit a Copy" and make a copy to a res. dict. OR find an existing under "Edit Additional Templates. In other words, somewhere there's some XAML to edit, just have to find it.

Comment: I have tried "Edit a Copy", but it comes out empty. In Blend There is one element in the object tree, and that is ControlTemplate. This is how it looks in xaml: <ControlTemplate x:Key="MessagePromptControlTemplate1" TargetType="Controls:MessagePrompt"/>

Comment: Right, there's normally also an "Edit additional templates" option under the Edit A Copy option that will reveal your template parts if Edit A Copy doesn't do the trick first. Somewhere though there will be the template that creates that control, once you find the XAML for that you're golden.

Comment: The "Edit additional templates" option is grayed out in Blend!

Comment: Ya that's kind of ridiculous, I looked at the documentation http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MessagePrompt&referringTitle=Documentation and it appears they only provide info on how to inject a little custom style but they don't talk about the overall style at all. Which is too bad since not everyone wants that black block rectangle in their design. You might inquire directly on their discussion board. Sorry I couldn't be more helpful, best of luck!

Comment: No problem! I'l guess I will need to download the source code and fix this myself! Annoying since the library itself is quite good...

Comment: If you do you should submit it back, maybe they could use your changes. I'm sure you're not the only one that would like to have ability to customize a control. Cheers!

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am facing similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044946/how-to-remove-the-border-in-coding4fun-messageprompt

Comment: I got my problem solved....you can check the link in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is template of MessagePrompt from Code4fun:

```
<Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
     <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />
     <Border VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Margin="10" // because this line you can't change margin
             Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
             BorderThickness="1" // because this line you can't change BorderThickness
             BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">
     <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" 
           Margin="0,-10,-25,10" FontSize="30" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" />
            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Body}" />
            <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0"
                        Name="actionButtonArea"
                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
      </StackPanel>
   </Border>
</Grid>
```

Padding ignored because this property not uses in template.
How you see, if you want to change this properties you have to change template of MessagePrompt.