# How to remove the border in Coding4Fun MessagePrompt

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I followed this example to display my usercontrol inside Coding4Fun MessagePrompt.
http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Creating-a-Windows-Phone-7-Trial-Application-Adding-Buy-Now-Functionality

When the Home icon at the bottom of the page is clicked I open MessagePromt which has my UserControl with two buttons as shown in image below.

But for some reason there appears this light white border, I am unable to determine from where it is coming.

**Note:** I have set border Transparent and 0 thickness for my usercontorl and all controls inside it.
I just want to show the blue panel and no white border and it's width is 300 as what it is seen.

Does any one has any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got help from **"Eric Fleck - Microsoft"** on apphub forums. Here's his solution:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage    
    ...    
    xmlns:c4f="clr-namespace:Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls;assembly=Coding4Fun.Phone.Controls">   

    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>  
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MsgPropmtNoBorder" TargetType="c4f:MessagePrompt">   
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">   
                <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}" />  

                <Border VerticalAlignment="Top"    
                        Margin="10"    
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"    
                        BorderThickness="0"    
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}">   

                    <StackPanel Margin="10">   
                        <TextBlock    
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Title}"    
                                    Margin="0,-10,-25,10"    
                                    FontSize="30"    
                                    TextWrapping="Wrap" FontFamily="Segoe WP Light" />  
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Body}" />  
                        <StackPanel    
                                    Margin="0,10,0,0"  
                                    Name="actionButtonArea"  
                                    Orientation="Horizontal"  
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" />  
                    </StackPanel>  

                </Border>  
            </Grid>  

        </ControlTemplate>  
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


        MessagePrompt prompt = new MessagePrompt();    
        prompt.Body = new WPUC();    
        prompt.ActionPopUpButtons.Clear();    
        prompt.Overlay = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(155, 41, 41, 41));   
        prompt.Template = (ControlTemplate)this.Resources["MsgPropmtNoBorder"];   

        prompt.Show();
```

Here's the resultant popup:
[image]

Comment: @NadAnd, the xml code goes in the .xaml of your page that contains the button that will open your popup. So in my case the Home button in the lower left corner is my button that is inside a user control. So I put the xml code in my UC's .xaml. But I think you might be able to put it in the app.xaml as well which I haven't tried. Then you will need to refer the template accordingly in the code-behind.

Comment: I did that but the body also disappeared

Comment: Another question .. Is there any way to do this without XAML?

Comment: @NadAnd I am not sure. Do you mind posting your code or may be just try out in a sample page and post it. You might want to try posting it on windows Phone dev center forums.

Answer (score 0):

I played a bit with the MessagePrompt control, it couldn't found any way to disable or hide the border. It's a shadow kind of effect in MessagePrompt control to provide a popup like appearance.

However, Eventhough you cannot remove it, you can reduce it's effect by setting the Width property of the MessagePrompt equal to your actual blue UserControl ( 300 in this case).

Comment: I already tried that but for some reason it would add some sort of padding or margin. I have set padding,margin etc for my control to 0. I will give it a try again though.