# removing the border in MessagePrompt

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, border

I'm using Coding4Fun prompt message to display a popup message on WP7 (Windows Phone 7).

I searched on how can I remove the white border around the message prompt and I found the following

[How to remove the border in Coding4Fun MessagePrompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11044946/how-to-remove-the-border-in-coding4fun-messageprompt)

I want to perform the solution, but I don't know where to place the XAML code in the answer.

Can any one clarify the answer please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You place it as a child of `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage>` obviously.

Example given:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage x:Class="Your.Class"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    Some other namespace declarations >

    <!-- Your page resources dictionary -->
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>  
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="MsgPropmtNoBorder"
                         TargetType="c4f:MessagePrompt">
                 BLAH-BLAH-BLAH
        </ControlTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <!-- Your layout root and all the page content -->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
          Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        BLAH-BLAH-BLAH-YOUR-CONTENT

    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```